# Can you see and bulk modify tags or update the tags of multiple different contacts on one screen?

Tags: tags, multiple-records

Just as I am able to modify update multiple contacts using profiles for other attributes, I want to also do that for tags but I can't seem to get the tags to expose themselves when I have a profile with tags. The tags column just appears as a blank.

I know you can assign tags to multiple contacts, but I want to be able to see current tags and edit tags for each one individually on one screen without having to visit each contact page separately.

Latest WP/Civi

Comment: not possible afaik. does the old fashioned Search Builder (not SearchKit) help a bit, in as much as you get a list showing all Tags (i assume), you could then filter to find all those with Apple, then change them via Actions to 'Green apples' or 'red apples'?

Comment: I used search builder to find all the contacts with X tag but without  A, B, C, D, G tags. then manually went to each contact and changed their tags. Time consuming, but it's done.